# Como añadir y quitar texto o elementos de dos DIVs

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo dos contenedores, #campoBusq y #categoria.

El DIV de #categoria lo lleno de elementos `option` iterando sobre la salida de una consulta mysql. Cada uno de esos `option` al pincharlo, inserta en  #campoBusq una cadena de texto equivalente a su contenido.

Lo que quiero es que si pincho un option por segunda vez, no me añada el texto por segunda vez sino que, por el contrario, me remueva esa cadena de texto de #campoBusq.

**Desde index.php**

```
<div id="campoBusq"></div>
<div id="categoria"> include("selectCategJquery.php"); </div>
```

**Desde selectCategJquery**

```
<?php 
    include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 
?>

<script>
  $('document').ready(function() {

  <?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

    while ($paisBuscado = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
       $categoria = utf8_encode($paisBuscado['idCategoria']);
  ?>
       var categoriajs= "<?php echo $categoria ?>";
       $('#categoria').append('<option value="'+ categoriajs +'" >' + categoriajs +'</option>');
  <?php  
    }

    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    $conexion->close();
  ?>

    $('option').click(function(){
      var valor = $(this).text();
        if( $('#campoBusq').text().indexOf(valor) == -1 ){
            $('#campoBusq').append(valor);
        }else{
          $('#campoBusq').splid(valor);
        }

    });

  });
</script>
```

*Asi esta Ahora*
[image: Asi esta Ahora]

*Esto es lo que Busco Hacer Espero que sea util el ejemplo de esta imagen*
[image: Esto es lo que Busco Hacer Espero que sea util el ejemplo de esta imagen]

Comment: tienes que explicar mejor lo que quieres hacer, no uses el título como contenido de la pregunta, o te la van a cerrar de nuevo

Comment: El color Purpura es #Categoria y el Azul es #campoBusq, quiero que al dar click al text(); sea en ambas se remueva del #campoBusq

Comment: Pero pon eso como parte de tu pregunta, no de los comentarios

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo a Utilizar esta red men

Comment: editala porfa; quiero explicar mejor pero debo ir aprendiendo con sus criticas constructivas

Comment: Tu pregunta no esta muy clara, ¿qué es? "ambas perspectivas" y el text de que objeto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu enfoque es incorrecto por dos razones:

1. Estás añadiendo options dentro de un DIV. Las opciones deben ir dentro de un delect, y para lo que estás haciendo lo mismo sirve un DIV hijo.
2. Cuando añades un elemento al contenedor #campoBusq, lo haces concatenando el texto, lo cual imposibilita quitarlo de ahí de manera limpia.

Pienso que debieras reestructurar tu código para que cada categoría tuviese su propio div. Que al pincharlas en un contenedor, se cambien al otro. De esa manera no necesitas manejar el caso de uso de pinchar algo que ya está seleccionado.

Te dejo una demostración

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
      jQuery(this).appendTo('#campoBusq');
    });
    
    jQuery('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
      jQuery(this).appendTo('#categoria');
    });

});
```

```css
 
#campoBusq {
border: 1px solid blue ;
width:45%;
float:left;
padding:5px;
height:200px;

}

#categoria {
border: 1px solid red;
width:45%;
padding:5px;
float:left;
height:200px;
}

.elemento {
border: 1px solid green;
width:90%;
margin:1%;
padding:1%;
float:left;
clear:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="campoBusq"></div>
  <div id="categoria">
    <div class="elemento">Chile</div>
    <div class="elemento">México</div>
    <div class="elemento">Perú</div>
    <div class="elemento">España</div>
    <div class="elemento">Argentina</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Si tu si entendiste la pregunta, podrías editarla y redactarla mejor....

Comment: La entendí porque proviene de otra pregunta que fue cerrada, y era más explicativa que esta. Voy a añadirle un poco de contexto

Comment: wow, gracias :-)

Comment: Si es algo asi pero quiero que no se remueva de categoria, me entiendes

Comment: y como podria registrar en la base de datos ????